# Separate HashiCorp Vault for each environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, google-cloud-platform, hashicorp-vault

Should I consider a HashiCorp Vault per environment? I feel like we shouldn't be combining development, staging, and production secrets within one environment. Is this something that you're doing at your organization or are you approaching this differently based on cost restrictions, etc.

Context:
https://www.vaultproject.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vault [Namespace](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/enterprise/namespaces) is designed to handle such scenarios.

> Namespaces are isolated environments that functionally exist as "Vaults within a Vault." They have separate login paths and support creating and managing data isolated to their namespace.

N.B.: This feature is **available** in all versions of **Vault Enterprise**.

Comment: I'll have to reach out to review enterprise costs but look into an alternatives using open-source HashiCorp Vault :)